# Getting the previous screen navigation items after push iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, navigationbar

[image]

Project has been build using Xcode 8. But if the project runs on iOS 11 it comes like as in the image. For iOS 10 and below its working fine. That is first controller navigation bar carries a logo, when i push from first controller the logo also appears on the second controller(no logo on second controller) only for the first push. Can any one help me with this?

this is the push code. Nothing is added new. works fine other than ios 11

```
if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "weather_ViewController_id") as? weather_ViewController
{
  viewController.cityname = "chennai"

  if let navigator = navigationController
  {
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = " "
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need show some code to see what is going on here

Comment: your `weather_ViewController` is a subclass of UIViewController?

Comment: yes it is the subclass

Comment: Sorry I mean if `weather_ViewController` is a subclass of UIViewController directly

Comment: yes it is the direct subclass

Comment: try using `viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil`